# Installing Braid

Tags: software-center, 14.10, games

Some time ago I bought the game Braid from the Ubuntu Software Center, but in Ubuntu 14.10 I has been removed and I cannot install it anymore. It is still listed in the Ubuntu Apps Directory, but only for Ubuntu versions up to 14.04. Is there a way to install this game in 14.10? I'd hate to lose this game because I paid for it.